# Mysql DeadLock On Update

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo

I'm working with Cake 2.1.2

This is my action in the controller:

```
$this->News->updateAll(
    array('News.Unread' => 0),
    array('News.Id <=' => $lastNewsId, 'RequestingUserId' => $current['id'])
);
```

**Sometime** I've this error and I get 500:
[PDOException] SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

I'm sure that in any scripts there aren't locks. 
What do I have to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the SQL it generates?

Comment: I have find the problem that cause that. The mysql events. I've some scheduled events, and probably these simple queries(i'm sure no locks on that) make some lock.. I don't know how.. but i'm going to move these queries out from mysql.

Comment: having a similar issue with CakePHP 3. I suspect it is due to the fact how CakePHP ORM works

Comment: Are you using transaction with the function above?

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent that possibly by changing the engine type on the table to InnoDB.